# Unity AR Foundation: Hot to get the current tracked Image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm new to the Unity AR foundation plugin and I'm currently trying to get the current image which is tracked by the camera. I Use the trackedImagesChanged delegate of the ARTrackedImageManager class to get informations about the images from the ReferenceLibrary. So this method gives me only all images from the ReferenceLibrary. Is there a way to get only the current tracked image? I'm searching for something like "getCurrentTrackedImage()" or a delegate which gives me the current tracked image.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

At the `trackedImagesChanged` event you should subscribe and work with `ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs imgChangedArgs`.

```
// Finding and subscribing for event on changing finding tracked images.
void Subscribe()
{
    var arTrackedImageManager = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<ARTrackedImageManager>();
    _arTrackedImageManager.trackedImagesChanged += ImageChangedHandle;
}

// Method handling found/lost tracked images.
void ImageChangedHandle(ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs imgChangedArgs)
{
    // loop over new found images. imgChangedArgs.added is List<ARTrackedImage>
    foreach (var item in imgChangedArgs.added)
    {
        var go = item.gameObject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs holds the all the tracked and lost targets.

This is how you can access it.

```
void OnEnable()
{
    m_TrackedImageManager.trackedImagesChanged += OnTrackedImagesChanged;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    m_TrackedImageManager.trackedImagesChanged -= OnTrackedImagesChanged;
}

void OnTrackedImagesChanged(ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
{

    foreach (ARTrackedImage trackedImg in eventArgs.added.Concat(eventArgs.updated))
    {

        if (trackedImg.trackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
        {
            //trackedImg is tracked

        }
        else
        {
            //trackedImg is lost  
        }
    }
}
```